# Nginx: redirect custom domain http requests to https

Tags: http, nginx

We want to redirect `something.custom.com` http requests to https, leaving the other requests unchanged. Tried something like below, but it didn't work:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  server_name _;

  if ($host ~ ^(.*?)\.custom\.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  root /www/example/public;
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on ssl;

  server_name _;

  root /www/example/public;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my setup?

Comment: This will redirect all requests to the domain custom.com to the HTTPS version. If you're targeting a specific sub-domain, rather specify the server name. Eg `server { listen 80; server_name something.custom.com; return 301 https://something.custom.com;}`

Comment: But I want to redirect the custom domain only. If I do like you said, then I will need to have another entry for other non-custom domain, like `server { listen 80; server_name _ }` which won't work. Nginx complains multiple entry listens to port 80. How do you solve that?

Comment: Nginx shouldn't have a problem with multiple `listen 80;` directives, as long as they're in separate server blocks with no `server_name` conflicts. See a temporary solution below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the configuration below should work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name something.custom.com;
    return 301 https://something.custom.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    #Rest of your config here
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=on ssl;

    server_name _;

    root /www/example/public;
}
```

Comment: Nginx reload was fine. But in the browser I saw too_many_redirects error. Any idea?

Comment: Then something is happening in your `listen 443;` block. Can you post your **full** config please?